# Is there a way to serialize all values of an enum with JSON in Kotlin?

Tags: json, spring-boot, rest, kotlin, enums

I have the following enum:

```
enum class Difficulty {
    EASY, MEDIUM, HARD
}
```

My Rest API is working in the following way: I have classes, and every class has a classManagementService, which helps to list every Response. Like this:

```
@Service
class RecipeManagementService (@Autowired private val recipeRepository: RecipeRepository,
                               private val addRecipeRequestTransformer: AddRecipeRequestTransformer) {

    fun findAll(): List<RecipeResponse> = this.recipeRepository.findAll().map(Recipe::toRecipeResponse)
```

RecipeResource.kt

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = [BASE_RECIPE_URL])
class RecipeResource(private val recipeManagementService: RecipeManagementService)
{
    @GetMapping
    fun findAll(): ResponseEntity<List<RecipeResponse>> = ResponseEntity.ok(this.recipeManagementService.findAll())
```

RecipeResponse.kt

```
data class RecipeResponse (var id:Long,
                           var name:String,
                           var ingredient:List<Ingredient>?,
                           var process:String?,
                           var category: List<Category>?,
                           var difficulty: Difficulty?)
```

I want the /api/v1/difficulty request to list all the difficulties. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every enum class has a generated `values()` method you can use to get an array of all possible values:

```kotlin
val allDifficulties: Array<Difficulty> = Difficulty.values()
```

So you can just return that in your controller, or use `toList()` if you want to return a `List`.